# Use of parameter expansion inside of a declaration to create dynamic variable names when required. (bash)

Tags: bash

Example code I'd love to work.
We'll assume there are 7 lines in a document, and I want to define parameters based on the contents therein. Other documents may have 1 line, or 29 lines, it varies greatly.

```
index=1; 
lines=$(cat /tmp/linedoc.txt | wc -l); 
while [ $index -le $lines ]; 
do declare lineLabel$index=$(cat /tmp/linedoc.txt | awk "NR==$index" | cut -d ' ' -f3); 
declare lineValue$index=$(cat /tmp/linedoc.txt | awk "NR==$index" | cut -d ' ' -f4); 
declare lineAddress$index=$(cat /tmp/linedoc.txt | awk "NR==$index" | cut -d ' ' -f5); 
((++index)); 
done; 
index=1; 
while [ $index -le $lines ]; 
do echo "$lineLabel$index $lineValue$index $lineAddress$index" >> /tmp/importantvalues.txt
done;
```

Now obviously the echo line isn't going to work the way i want it, how do i force parameter expansion to expand $lineValue1, $lineValue2 and so on, rather than $lineValue and $index separately?

Is this even possible? the bash version is 3.5, and associative arrays aren't an option, and updating them to 4+ isn't an option as this version is deployed on more than 4000 machines, all managed individually.

```
cat /tmp/linddoc.txt
line1 line john 1 5555555555
line2 line jacob 2 5555555555
line3 BLF jingle 3 5555555555
line4 line heimer 4 5555555555
line5 BLF schmidt 5 5555555555
line6 SD bob 6 5555555555
line7 SD connor 7 5555555555
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the problem; from your example `/tmp/linddoc.txt`, what is your expected outcome?

Comment: What's wrong with numeric-indexed arrays for this? Also, reading the entire file over & over again for each line is a waste of time; use a `while IFS=' ' read _ _ Label Value Address _; do ... done <tmp/linedoc.txt` loop (see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).

Comment: See [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for the general case.

Comment: (...and, to store your data in numerically-indexed arrays -- as is suited to your specific case -- also see [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005))

Comment: BTW, get out of the `cat foo | ...` habit. To give you an example, `wc -c <file` or `wc -c file` is constant-time because it can seek to the end of the file and ask for the offset, but `cat file | wc -c` is O(n) because it has a FIFO that can only be read front-to-back -- it needs to actually read the whole file to know how long it is, so it gets slower as your files grow. Other tools (`tail`, `sort`, etc) have similar optimizations that become impossible when you force them to read from FIFOs.

Comment: (also, instead of putting `>>outfile` on the `echo` _inside_ your loop, put `>outfile` after the `done` so you only open the output file _once_ and leave it open for the full loop)

Comment: In addition, see [BashFAQ/119 - What's the difference between "cmd < file" and "cat file | cmd"? What is a UUOC?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119).

Comment: I've read over that linked solution dozens of times before even posting this question. I don't understand it. I can't wrap my head around it, or i'm doing it wrong. But when i type index=1; declare lineValue$index="foo"; test=lineValue$index; echo ${!test} I DO get foo, so then i do this... index=2; lineValue$index="bar"; test=lineValue$index; echo ${!test} and i get "bar" but... i do index=1; echo ${!lineValue$index}, and i get "bar", so i check with "set" what my variables are, and the only thing that's been set is lineValue, no lineValue1 or lineValue2. I'm stumped.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Not sure how to give you credit for the answer, but while you may not have answered my confusion, you provided me with not only a way to do what I wanted, but better, but you also gave me a way to do it faster with IFS. Thanks so much. KUDOS.

Comment: `index=1; printf -v "lineValue$index" %s "value"` to set `lineValue1` to `value` in a manner compatible with bash 3.x -- but we've all been telling you _not to do that_ and to use arrays instead (if you need to store more than one line in memory at a time all, which it appears you don't). Using `declare` with dynamic content on the left-hand side of the `=` has security problems -- it's effectively `eval`-equivalent.

Comment: @DavidConway I'm not sure what's going on in your tests -- `lineValue$index="bar"` (without `declare`) and `echo ${!lineValue$index}` are both invalid bash syntax (they should cause "command not found" and "bad substitution" errors, respectively). But in general, dynamic variable names are a mess and should be avoided whenever possible. Just use numeric-index arrays: `index=1; lineValue[index]="foo"; echo "${lineValue[index]}"`. As for credit (points), don't worry about it; I have plenty.